# refactor performCrop() method out of activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, crop, android-crop

I have a PerformCrop method which works perfectly.

I want to move it to my 'util' class so i can call it in other activities. There are complications to this in that it uses intents which return to the calling class. I think this should be no issue but maybe i'm incorrect.

Here is what i have tried and the issue i am seeing

1. I cut and paste performCrop() to my util class.
2. I had an error at 'startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);' where it didnt recognise the method so i extended the class with 'Extends Activity'
3. When it runs it errors and im not 100% sure why but an exception is caught

> 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference'

Here is the method, below that is the 'onActivityResult' method. Can anyone tell me how to move the performCrop() to a non Activity extended class?

Code

```
public void performCrop(Uri picUri)
{
    final int CROP_IMAGE = 2;
        /*
* PERFORM CROP
* this must take into account he fact we may not have a crop method on phone, or the diff ways diff OS crop
 */
    //NEXUS 5 OS 5 is example of this branch
    // take care of exceptions
    try {
        // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
        // support it)

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // // // indicate output X and Y

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"This device doesn't support the crop action! Exception: " + anfe.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
    {//NOT TESTED AS HW DOES NOT GO HERE
        System.out.println("out of memory");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { //NOT TESTED AS HW DOES NOT GO HERE
        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        //display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", width);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Called from Activity when the camera intent returns successful result. Note the crop intent will also retun to this method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK )
    {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE) //reply from camera
        {
            toolbox.performCrop(uri); //crop the picture
        }

        if(requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) //reply from crop
        {
           /* Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(uri);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);*/
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap bmp = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imgViewProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY) //reply from gallery
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            uri = data.getData();
            toolbox.performCrop(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create A Class name CropImage, put your method performCrop() in it and call it from wherever you want as,

```
                CropImage cropImage = new CropImage(this);
                cropImage.performCrop(uri);
```

The CropImage claas would look like,

```
public class CropImage {
Context context;

public CropImage(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void performCrop(Uri picUri)
{
    final int CROP_IMAGE = 2;
    /*
    * PERFORM CROP
    * this must take into account he fact we may not have a crop method on phone, or the diff ways diff OS crop
    */
    //NEXUS 5 OS 5 is example of this branch
    // take care of exceptions
    try {
        // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
        // support it)

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // // // indicate output X and Y

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"This device doesn't support the crop action! Exception: " + anfe.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
    {//NOT TESTED AS HW DOES NOT GO HERE
        System.out.println("out of memory");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { //NOT TESTED AS HW DOES NOT GO HERE
        Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        //display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", width);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_IMAGE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this not same as what i have done except putting performcrop() in its own class as opposed to a class called 'toolbox'?

Comment: Worked a charm r j - splendid lad. So can you tell me in a few sentences what you did to do that and why it ant go into my toolbox class?

Comment: Very simple, you first create an object of the the class CropImage and their you send "this" i.e. context from which android understands which activity it is, so now if this class is called from any activity, it's context is passed and with which the activities are differentiated. Also you may have noticed the context passed is type casted into activity as ((Activity)context) at some places so that we can call the Activity methods..!

Answer (score 0):

### First You Check The Where Result Going

```
ifgetpaternt==null)
{
Startactivityforreslt(your intent,code);
}
else
{
getpaprent().Startactivityforreslt(your intent,code);
}
```

If Getpaprent() method call Then result send to parent activity .
so get result in parent activity and resend to your activity .....